# Passing a variable from a K2 template to a RSForm's field default value

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have a variable

```
$price = $this->item->extraFields->price->value;
```

in the item.php which is Joomla page detail template. In the same template, I load a form using RSForm component, so it's just {rsform 8}. In the form, you can set default values to its fields.

I want to set one of the fields' default value to be the $price - that's just an integer. So I followed this tutorial http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/369-get-the-page-title.html

and also this one 
http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-article/77-display-php-variables-by-default-when-form-is-shown.html (the same + SQL variant).

However, whenever I try to put there the default value, I don't succeed. I've been looking all around the internet for 3 hours so far and I just can't seem to do what I need.

So in my desperation, I tried different approaches to insert the variable into the form like the following...

```
//<code>
return $price;    
//</code>

//<code>
$p = $price,
return $p;    
//</code>

//<code>
echo $price;    
//</code>

//<code>
print $price;    
//</code>

//<code>
$price;    
//</code>
```

None of them worked, of course. However, this one works:

```
//<code>
$price = 10;
return $price;    
//</code>
```

I think the problem is that the template of the page (item.php) is somehow separated from the RSForm form template, but I don't really know.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue? Another thing I'm gonna try is adding the variable there via JavaScript, but I'm not much into it as people can have JS off (and the field has to be filled no matter what), and I still can't be sure that it will be possible that way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to reply my questions when I solved this, so here it is, a bit lately - using javascript.

```
// Creating a variable and filling it with the prize
<?php $price = $this->item->extraFields->price->value; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
// Filling a javascript variable with the php variable
var c1 = "<?php echo $price; ?>";

// Filling my HTML input field in the form with the variable
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = c1;
</script>
```

And whoa, the form is filled with the variable. Of course the script gets complicated with some conditions and next siblings, but that's another story.